# java spring recursion problem with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, stack-overflow

Hello I am new to java spring, and I have a problem when I want to log a user.
I got the error :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null

Thanks a lot^^

```java
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    /** Injecté par le setter */
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String token = extractTokenFromHeader(request);
            UserDetails user = userService.getUserFromJwt(token);
            setPrincipalInSecurityContext(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Impossible de trouver le token", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String extractTokenFromHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setPrincipalInSecurityContext(UserDetails user) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
    }

    /// Setters ///
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

[screenshot UserService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlfUw.png)